# Formating integers in percentage in php

Tags: php

I have two integers that are `$hours = 74` and `$minutes = 20`, the format I need to get them in is following: hours and minutes (without any spacing) in percentage of one hour. So in this case the final result should be 7433.

Just to make it more clear if the two numbers would be `$hours = 74` and `$minutes = 30`, the final result should be 7450.

I have been trying to look for similar functions, but without any success.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `$result = $hours . ($minutes / 60 * 100);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really what you are looking for is `$result = $hours . floor($minutes/60*100);` ?

Or if you need the leading zeroes: `$result = str_pad($hours,2,'0') . str_pad(floor($minutes/60*100),2,'0');`

Comment: Please note that this does not work if minutes would be higher than 60.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER now why would that be? (Hopefully you will answer before I leave office in 1 hour and 91 minutes)

Comment: Becaue if you have hour `74` and minutes let's say `80` your output would be `74133`. Because you concatinating the strings `74` and the result of the floored operation which is `133` for 80  minutes.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I meant why would OP use $minutes beyond 60 ? Did he state that anywhere? (Hurry, I leave in 1 hour and 85 minutes)

Comment: Did he state that he would not? I try always to build bullet proof solutions. Your solution is correct, but limited to the case that minutes are below 60. If this is always the case for the OP your solution is just fine. But we don't know it exactly.

Comment: While I do agree with @TiMESPLiNTER that there is nothing currently suggesting that OP is _not_ going to be using, say, 75 minutes. However, there is little suggesting he would, so there is a risk of overengineering the code. As it stands, this code works, and it works correctly with the base assumption that the minutes would be formatted as minutes. In the end of the day, there is the GIGO principle - feed some code garbage input, and you'll get garbage output. OP could pre-parse it to ensure correctness or modify the code, or a myriad of other things. We are not here to do the work instead.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that in the question, but number of minutes in this case will never exceed 59.

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself the pain of coming up with code that handles cases where the value of `$minutes` >= 60 by using the `DateTimeInterface` objects. I admit, they may seem overkill in this situation, but they are very sturdy and reliable. Plus, if ever you'd want to add days, weeks, months, years or seconds to this code, the `DateTimeInterface` classes are already equipped for the job:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$comp = clone $now;
//2 identical datetime instances
//add hours + minutes to either one
$comp->add(
    sprintf(
        'PT%dH%dM',
        $hours,
        $minuts
    )
);
//get difference in seconds
$diff = $comp->getTimeStamp() - $now->getTimeStamp();
//or echo, I used printf to limit the number of decimals to 2
printf(
    '%.2f hours difference'
    $diff/3600 //1 hour === 3600 seconds
);
```

Just browse [the `DateTime` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and other classes/interfaces like `DateInterval` and others implementing the `DateTimeInterface`.

Just for completeness, here's how I'd set about doing this *"manually"*

```
$decimalT = $hours + floor($minutes/60) + ($minutes%60)/60
//add hours in case $minutes>= 60
//floor($minutes/60);
//get remainder minutes, converted to decimal hours
//($minutes%60)/60;
printf(
    '%d hours + %d seconds == %.2f hours',
    $hours,
    $minutes,
    $decimalT
);
```

Comment: If you `floor()` the calculation of `$diff/3600` you get also the correct result. Very smart solution! But I think the performance of plain calculation is a lot better then your `DateTimeInterface` solution. And also it's less code which can do exactly the same.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: Direct calculation is definitely the better approach perfomance-wise. I also stated in my answer that for a task as simple as this, this approach may seem like overkill. But we don't know what else the OP is trying to do, and the main advantage of using `DateTimeInterface` objects, to me, is that it is flexible, reliable, and easy to expand on. But yes: _"manual"_ computation is quicker but (if you add weeks, and seconds), it quickly becomes unmaintainable

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet of code:

```
$hours = 74;
$minutes = 20;

$totalMinutes = $hours * 60 + $minutes;
$percentage = floor(($totalMinutes * 100) / 60);

var_dump($percentage);
```